# packet is too small while reading frames from video

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a single script which takes an arbitrary number of frames from a video and saves them as images: here goes the code.

```
def get_n_frames(n, k, src, dst):
# read n frames from video in src and save them as images on folder dst. If dst does not exists, it is created.
# if n == -1, are saved as many frames as posiible
# k is the number of frames to skip between each pair of frames (ie save only one out of k)

    max_intentos = 10
    end_of_video = 0


    while True:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        if cap.isOpened():
            break
        if max_intentos:
            raise "Capture is not open. There may be a problem with source {}".format(src)
        print("trying again")
        max_intentos -=1

    try:
        i=0
        frame_number = 0 
        while(frame_number < n or n==-1):
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if ret:
                end_of_video = 0
                if i % k == 0:

                    final_dest = join(dst, '{0}_{1:03}.jpg'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'), frame_number))
                if cv2.imwrite(final_dest, frame):
                    print("Saving frame {}".format(frame_number))
                    frame_number +=1
                i+=1
            elif end_of_video < 10:
                end_of_video +=1
            else:
                if n != -1:
                    print("WARNING: Video is too short, can not take {} frames with k={}".format(n, k))
                break
    finally:
        # When everything done, release the capture
        cap.release()
        print("{} frames were saved".format(frame_number))
```

I have used it for a lot of `.avi` videos, without problem, but now I'm getting an strange message: `[msvideo1 @ 0x5615d5f85280] Packet is too small` I've been searching on the net but this seems very strange, it's not an exception, output look as if program finished ok.

[image: this is how the program finishes]

I'm calling it with a .avi video as source, with its relative path, k=10 and n=-1

I'm not sure if those are all frames from the video and more important, what is this strange error?

Comment: Is the error for just one specific video or have you gotten it for multiple files? Could the file/frame be corrupted?

Comment: It happen in two out of 30 videos. How can I check if is the file corrupt? The extracted frames 1732 and 1733 are ok.

Comment: I don't know. Is it possible to share one video that works and one that doesn't?